# class defination in c# with different method

Tags: c#, class

I want to define a class in C#.  I found these two methods:

Method 1 :

```
public class customer
{
   private string _name ;
   private string _family;

   public string Name
   {
      get { return __name; }
      set { if(value=="")message(" نام کارخانه را وارد کنید ");
          _name= value; }
   }

   public string Family
   {
      get { return _family; }
      set { if(value=="")message(" نام کارخانه را وارد کنید ");
          _family= value; }
   }

   public void AddCustomer() 
   {
      add _name and _family to database
   }
}
```

Method 2:

```
public class customer
{
   public void AddCustomer(string name ,string family) 
   {
      //code to add a customer
   }
}
```

I am confused; which one should be used, and what the difference between these two methods? Which one is better and is more commonly used?

Comment: This is more of a matter of preference and context.

Comment: Except that in method 1, _name and _family are private.  How would they ever get set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't do either of these. You're introducing a method called `AddCustomer` *on a `customer` class*. I wouldn't expect a `Customer` to know about a database - I'd expect some sort of data access layer or customer repository to know about it instead.

A `Customer` may well have a constructor taking a name and family, or whatever, and then your `CustomerRepository` would have an `Add(Customer)` method.

To think of it another way: I would expect it to make perfect sense to use the `Customer` class (which should have a capital `C` to conform with .NET naming conventions) without any knowledge of a database, therefore *it* probably shouldn't know about the database.

Admittedly I do break these own rules myself in terms of custom XML serialization, allowing a static `FromXElement` method and an instance method of `ToXElement`... but at least that doesn't involve external dependencies.

Comment: I couldn't have said it any better myself, +1.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, _name and _family are private in method 1.  There is no way to set those.  You would need to define them as public.

Second, that is a very loaded question.  Sometimes it makes sense to encapsulate members and sometimes you want to pass them inline in the method call itself.  There is no "better way".

Comment: So when we should pass it in inline and when it should be encapsulate?

Comment: I can't condense years of programming experience down to an answer on StackOverflow.  Trial and error are your best friends now.